# return statement causes Rust to seemingly have a mutable and shared reference at the same time

Tags: rust

I have the following code :

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    for _ in v.iter() {
        v[0] = 0;
        // return;
    }
}
```

It does not compile, and I see why, since I'm attempting to have a shared (`v.iter()`) and mutable (`v[0] = 0`) reference of `v` at the same time.

However, uncommenting the `return` statement makes this code compile, and I'm not sure why. I guess that the compiler somehow manages to know that the shared reference to `v` can be dropped before the mutable borrow occurs, but how exactly does it knows that ?

In this exemple, what would be the lifetimes of the two borrows of `v` ?

Comment: I think it has to do with early termination of the loop, since return breaks the loop and only runs once; it might be unrolling the loop into a single iteration of `v.iter()` that is immediately dropped and then mutating the vector afterwards

Answer (score 6):

A `for` loop is just syntactic sugar for a loop with a manual iterator:

```
for x in c {
   //...
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
let mut __iterator = c.into_iter();
while let Some(x) = __iterator.next() {
   //...
}
```

So for your original code that would be:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let mut __iterator = v.iter().into_iter();
    while let Some(_) = __iterator.next() {
        v[0] = 0;
        // return;
    }
}
```

(The call to `into_iter()` is redundant here, because using that with an iterator just returns itself.)

This code fails just like yours, as expected.

But if you uncomment the return, then the compiler knows that the loop never repeats, so it is transformed as if:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let mut __iterator = v.iter().into_iter();
    if let Some(_) = __iterator.next() {
        v[0] = 0;
    }
}
```

Now, *non-lexical lifetimes (NLL)* kick in, and sees that `iterator` is not used beyond the call to `next()` so it can be dropped just there. The `_` does not count because it is not a real bind, but even if you wrote `_x` instead, NLL would drop it immediately as it is not used further. Thus `v` is no longer borrowed and the assignment to `v[0]` is perfectly safe and legal.

If you keep the original borrow of `v` alive it will fail again:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let mut __iterator = v.iter().into_iter();
    if let Some(x) = __iterator.next() {
        v[0] = 0; // error! v is still borrowed
        dbg!(x);
    }
}
```

This fails with a nice explanation:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/main.rs:5:9
  |
3 |     let mut __iterator = v.iter().into_iter();
  |                          -------- immutable borrow occurs here
4 |     if let Some(x) = __iterator.next() {
5 |         v[0] = 0;
  |         ^ mutable borrow occurs here
6 |         dbg!(x);
  |              - immutable borrow later used here
```

Comment: You might want to desugar one more level into bare `loop { ... }`

Comment: @PitaJ: Sure you could, but I was just trying to make the point of what the `return` in the middle of loop does: convert the `while` into an `if`. Changing it into a `loop/if/break` would just look more complicated.

Comment: My point is just that AFAIK, `for x in y` never gets lowered into a `while let Some(x) = iter.next()`, but directly into a `loop`. I believe the borrow checker runs on the lowered `loop`s.

Comment: @PitaJ Fair enough, that is expected because IIRIC `for` and `loop` loops exist since forever but `while let` loops are somewhat more recent. Anyway I prefer to move mentally from `for` to `while let`, it just feel more natural.